# No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl.split()

Tags: grails, ubuntu, groovy, ubuntu-12.04

Error Message:

```
No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl.split() 
is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [:]

Possible solutions: split(), split(), split(groovy.lang.Closure), 
plus(java.lang.String), wait(),toList()
```

Code snippet:

```
static getRosterId(def session) {
     session.filter?.split(':')[0]
}
static getSubject(def session) {
    session.filter?.split(':')[1]
}
```

JDK:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.12.04.4)OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

Grails Version:

```
2.0.1
```

Ubuntu Version:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-29-generic x86_64)
```

this is doing a split on what should be a normal String... of course it's a GString while in grails, this code works in production, on our local boxes, but does not work on our CI Ubuntu server.... not sure why Grails wouldn't be able to resolve String methods in this particular environment, we are not doing anything special in this class, no String.metaClass manipulation... straight Grails.

Any input would be awesome

Comment: You should check on **session.filter** value first. It looks like it's returned-value is not in desire.

Comment: I'd check with the Oracle JVM

Comment: @PhatH.VU it says that the value is a org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl which is a GStringImpl AKA GString Implementation. All GString methods should be available

Comment: @tim_yates we changed to the oracle JVM and it had the same issue :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our final fix was

```
static getRosterId(def session) {
     session.filter?.toString().split(':')[0]
}
static getSubject(def session) {
     session.filter?.toString().split(':')[1]
}
```

This should not be needed in Groovy! :( a GStringImpl Object should resolve all GString and java.lang.String methods :/

Comment: Do you have 2 versions of groovy loaded into the classpath somehow? This is odd